# Nativescript Angular How do i switch component (tabs template)

Tags: angularjs, nativescript

Hello i am new to nativescript-angular trying to solve how router is working.I read the documentation but because i am using a boilerplate i couldnt really understand how it is working...
https://github.com/NativeScript/template-tab-navigation-ng

I only added 1 component to this project which is an empty login component and i set it as a root component.
[image: files image]

What i am trying to do is how do i switch from my login component to tabs component ? with button func

app-routing.module.js:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

    { path: "", redirectTo: "/tabs", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "tabs", loadChildren: "./tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule" }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, NgModuleFactoryLoader, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,

    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a link to your component tab in your login component

```
this.router.navigate(["/tabs"]);
```